# Módulo ou manipulador assíncrono concluído enquanto a operação assíncrona estava pendente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, assincronismo

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail de forma assíncrona, sem precisar aguardar o retorno. Porém quando não uso o `await`  obtenho uma exceção no retorno para `action`. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
public Task MissaoAvaliada(string usuario, string destinatario)
{
    _email.From = new MailAddress("emaildeenvio@emaildeevnio.com");
    _email.To.Add(destinatario);
    _email.Subject = "Email";
    _email.Body = string.Format($"Aqui vai o texto");
    return _cliente.SendMailAsync(_email);
}
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Avaliar(RespostaViewModel viewModel)
{
     Resposta resposta = Mapper.Map<Resposta>(viewModel);
     Task teste;
     if (_respostaService.Update(resposta))
     {
         teste = _emailService.MissaoAvaliada("Leonardo", "meuemail");
         return RedirectToAction("Action", "controller");
     }
     else
         return View(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `SendMailAsync` ainda está sendo executado de maneira assíncrona quando o método `RedirectToAction` é executado, fazendo a código sair do escopo da Action `Avaliar`.
O problema é que a Action assíncrona `Avaliar` está sendo abandonada enquanto um método assíncrono (`SendMailAsync`) ainda está sendo executado e a variável `teste` está aguardando o resultado (`Task`) deste método.

Utilize a keywork `await`:

```
teste = await _emailService.MissaoAvaliada("Leonardo", "meuemail");
```

Ou se quiser utilizar o conceito "fire and forget" para que o método seja executado de forma que não seja necessário aguarda-lo, remova a variável `teste` e utilize este método:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _emailService.MissaoAvaliada("Leonardo", "meuemail"));
```

Não tenho certeza, mas talvez apenas remover a variável `teste`possa resolver este erro, pois o escopo não vai mais depender do resultado, mas eu prefiro o approach "fire and forget".