# Manipulador assíncrono concluído enquanto a operação assíncrona estava pendente - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Olá, tenho algumas dúvidas em relação ao código abaixo.

1. O código retorno o seguinte erro *[InvalidOperationException]: Módulo ou manipulador assíncrono concluído enquanto a operação assíncrona estava pendente.*
2. O método principal que chama essa task(este outro métodos) devolve um IHttpActionResult e a resposta do método SMSAsync acaba interferindo na resposta do meu método principal, ou seja, eu gostaria de voltar status 200 mesmo com erro no método do SMS - *já tentei try cath sem nenhum ação no cath*;

O primeiro item, resolvi usando a chamada deste método com uma *Task.Factory.StartNew*, já que neste caso, não preciso da resposta do método para seguir mas e se não fosse este o caso ?

```cs
public async void SMSAsync(String mobileNumber)
{

  Guid gui = Guid.NewGuid();

  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "Basic XPTO");               
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

    using (var content = new StringContent("{  " +
        "\"sendSmsRequest\": {    " +
        "\"from\": \"WeBlank\",    " +
        "\"to\": \"55" + mobileNumber + "\",    " +
        "\"schedule\": \"2014-08-22T14:55:00\",    " +
        "\"msg\": \"Aqui vai a mensagem de SMS.\",    " +
        "\"callbackOption\": \"NONE\",    " +
        "\"id\": " +
        "\"" + gui.ToString() + "\", "     +
        "\"aggregateId\": \"1111\",    " +
        "\"flashSms\": false  }}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 
        "application/json"))

    {
      using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api-rest.zenvia360.com.br/services/send-sms", content))
      {
          string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*https://gist.github.com/carloshenriqueribeiro/0b879e1655e7eedd605e264d50a45742*

**Como faço a chamada do método**

```cs
public IHttpActionResult CreateUser(ParticipanteCreateModel participante)
{
   // código que executa a criação do usuário
   String telefone;
   telefone = part.Telefone.Replace('-', ' ');
   telefone = telefone.Replace('(', ' ');
   telefone = telefone.Replace(')', ' ');
   telefone = telefone.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SMSAsync(telefone)); 

   return Ok(usuarioId);

}
```

Comment: Apesar de você estar abusando dos `using`, não consegui reproduzir o comportamento aqui... o método é executado sem problemas e ao final eu recebo a resposta de acesso negado (O que era esperado)

Comment: Inclua o código da sua action, de como você está invocando o método e atribuindo a sua resposta

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Módulo ou manipulador assíncrono concluído enquanto a operação assíncrona estava pendente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233348/m%c3%b3dulo-ou-manipulador-ass%c3%adncrono-conclu%c3%addo-enquanto-a-opera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ass%c3%adncrona-estava)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo o código é uma adaptação do site da prestadora de serviço (zenvia)
https://zenviasms.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/tabela-de-status/detailcode

Comment: @Barbetta não é pergunta duplicada. Li este item antes de abrir a minha pergunta ainda assim, obrigado.